# Unable to rund `brew doctor` or `brew list --cask` due to Cask error

Tags: homebrew

I just installed a new Cask and afterwards, I ran `brew doctor`, which returns `Error: Cask 'java' is unreadable: undefined method` undent' for #String:0x00007f8d77a0ae40`.

Java doesn't appear under `brew list`, so I tried `brew list --cask`, but got the same error message again. Running `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` returns:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.8.0_121, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. Do I need to re-install Java?

Comment: Maybe useful: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/49716#issuecomment-413515303. Although maybe upgrading homebrew would be best.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I came across this too and upgrading Homebrew and running that command fix didn't clear the error.

Comment: It could also be because your installed version of java is from an old version of the Cask file. I removed it via ``brew uninstall --force java`` and ``rm -r "$(brew --prefix)/Caskroom/java`` and ran  ``brew install java`` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I cleared the error by deleting the update .pkg file in `/usr/local/Caskroom/java/1.8.0_121-b13,e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441/`

Comment: This didn't change anything for me.